# GeoServer Web Admin Interface: 404 error

Tags: geoserver, ubuntu, boundless-suite, tomcat

I'm working through the [OpenGeo workshop](http://workshops.opengeo.org/suiteintro/geoserver/webadmin.html) and I'm stuck with setting up a GeoServer. When I try to access the Web Admin Interface `localhost:8080/geoserver/`, Tomcat reports a "HTTP 404 Status" error page. The same holds for the GeoWebCache configuration page.

Some additional info:

- My system: Ubuntu 13.04 with OpenGeo Suite 3.0.2 installed as described in the official reference. Things work fine on windows by the way.
- I started Tomcat 6.0.35 via `$/etc/init.d/tomcat6 start` as the [installation details](http://suite.opengeo.org/opengeo-docs/installation/linux/details.html) point out.
- The log-file of tomcat at `/var/log/tomcat6` reports a "severe" FileNotFoundException for the file masterpw.xml:

  ```
  SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.geoserver.platform.GeoServerContextLoaderListener
  org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
  Error occured reading security configuration;
  nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException:
  /usr/share/opengeo-suite-data/geoserver_data/security/masterpw.xml (No such file or directory)
  ```

  At the end of geoserver.log in `/var/log/geoserver` the following warning is reported:

  ```
  WARN [support.DisposableBeanAdapter] - Invocation of destroy method failed on bean with name 'geoServerLoader':
  org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationNotAllowedException:
  Error creating bean with name 'GWCLifeCycleHandler':
  Singleton bean creation not allowed while the singletons of this factory are in destruction (Do not request a bean from a BeanFactory in a destroy method implementation!)
  ```

I'm new to web mapping and the above steps together with an internet recherche didn't resolve my problem. Do you have any suggestions?

---

**Update:** Setting up a GeoServer outside of the OpenGeo framework works just fine. The key is that there is an OS-independent binary provided on GeoServer.org using a webapp bundled in Jetty instead of Apache Tomcat. The steps it took were:

1. Download and unzip `geoserver-2.3.2-bin.zip`.
2. Move the folder to your preferred installation path and cd into it.
3. Add the environmental variable JAVA_HOME to your PATH:

   ```
   export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-amd64/jre
   ```

   **Note**: This path is distribution dependent (here: Ubuntu 13.04)
4. Shut down the Apache Tomcat servlet engine:

   ```
   sudo service tomcat6 stop
   ```
5. Start up the Server by executing the provided java archive in the folder:

   ```
   java -jar start.jar
   ```
6. The Web Admin Interface is now available via web browser under

   ```
   localhost:8080/geoserver
   ```

However, I suspect that if one knows about how to assign port numbers etc it might still work with Apache as installed by the OpenGeo Suite. Suggestions are welcome.

Comment: It looks like your installation is corrupt, try deleting it and starting again.

Comment: it doesn't look that the whole installation is corrupt though, I'd say that you have a "root" problem. Based on `/usr/share/opengeo-suite-data/geoserver_data/security/masterpw.xml (No such file or directory)` when you're running geoserver or geoserver itself is trying to get things together with tomcat apache, things are not able to communicate due to permission problems. Try as root (`sudo` I think in ubuntu) and see if your problem goes away.

Comment: @iant: I've tried reinstalling already but this was no remedy (though not hunting down every file but using the synaptic package manager).

Comment: @Gery: sudo what exactly? I mean the config webpage should open without any previous actions except starting up tomcat maybe (which was done as root).

Comment: [this](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/09/ubuntu-tips-how-to-login-using-su-command-su-gives-authentication-failure-error-message/) could help you with the root thing, I think you only need `su -`, press enter and then enter the password. Where did you install tomcat? if you installed under `/usr/` then it belongs to the root domain, I normally install tomcat under `/opt/` in my rhel, so I can access there without being root and also have no problems when launch my app

Comment: Yes I think I get the idea of the user privileges as root but which modules should actually benefit from the additional rights? I don't start anything by hand except the tomcat servlet and the webbrowser.

As far as I understood it tomcat is installed in `/usr/share`. If everything fails I will try to reinstall it to `/opt` by hand.

Comment: or perhaps you just need to launch manually tomcat because you don't have an automatic script to do this, do you? check [this](http://chandrakanth15.wordpress.com/2010/12/16/how-to-install-and-configure-apache-tomcat-on-centosredhat/)

Comment: does /usr/share/opengeo-suite-data/geoserver_data/security/masterpw.xml actually exist - if it does then it's a permissions problem, if not then install is broken

Comment: @Gery: I start tomcat as mentioned in the question with the shell script `/etc/init.d/tomcat6` as root. It confirms proper execution with `* Starting Tomcat servlet engine tomcat6 [ OK ]`. Anyway thanks for your link, I will look it up.
@iant: it does NOT exist. There is however a file `masterpw.info` in the same folder containing a "generated master password" which should be tested "by logging in as root". Whatever that means... I will try to smoke out the whole opengeo-suite and reinstall properly.

Comment: A thorough reinstallation did not fix it. I updated my question with my working alternative solution which is based on an individual installation of geoserver independent of the OpenGeo installation routine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Suite 3.0.2 Ubuntu Packages don't work with Ubuntu 13.04.  Officially they are for Ubuntu 10.04 or 10.10 and they seem to work on 12.04 without trouble, but they break on 13.04.

Comment: Most probably true, I've just seen that the official install guide for Ubuntu states "This page will describe how to install GeoServer on Ubuntu 10.04 (Lucid). Later versions may work as well, but are not well-tested at this time." Truly, downgrading Ubuntu 13.04 to 12.04 resolved the problem for me.